# Constructor initializer list in code generation

Tags: dart

I am making a generator in Dart in [the analyzer package](https://pub.dev/packages/analyzer), and while I can access `ConstructorElement` and its `.parameters`, that only returns the constructor's parameters. I would also want to access the initializer list that is attached to this constructor.

```dart
class Target extends Equatable {
  final int alpha;
  
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [alpha];

  Target(int beta) : alpha = beta;
}
```

Using the `constructor.parameters` I can get a list of `ParameterElement` that would contain `[beta]` (simplified). I would also want to access the initializer list, so I can get stuff like `{alpha: beta}` etc., and work with these mappings.

From the parameter object, I can get `isInitializingFormal`, which tells me if that is `this.beta` or not. If so, one can access the field by casting to `FieldFormalParameterMember`.

I would want to do something similar for non-formal parameters to know which instance fields I already set from the constructor.

I found that there is something like `ConstructorFieldInitializer`, which might be possibly what I want; I just cannot find a way how to access it from the constructor object.